# How can I get SUMIFS to start over when there is a change of identifying data in a row? (to sum by "groups")

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

Currently SUMIFS calculates as intended for 200,000+ rows. There is one exception I can't figure out, when data is the same for 10 rows, then the 11th row changes and then row 12 through 21 contains the same data as the first 10 rows. SUMIFS is giving quantity for all 20 "like" rows instead of have two separate sum totals for each set of 10. The goal is splitting up the quantities without breaking apart the spreadsheet.[Excel sheet example](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AuNuscW0QsRugZx6IKfK0vt63lqmfA?e=NbgcFc)

Comment: Aaron, I don't understand your question even if l look at the spreadsheet. And I even understand German. :)

Comment: I am running sumifs formula to calculate original quantity in column 'K'. Quantities counting top to bottom, instead of row by row consecutive, illustrated by highlighting those rows. It's fine until duplicate group exists where it makes a group appear to have more than it should in a particular area. One item that has a quantity of 36, it has 36 line items instead of 1 line item 36. This is seen in column 'L'. 290,000 lines in original document condensed by macro down to under 50,000 line items but I have to calculate the quantities before I do that.

Comment: For clarification, this example comes from a top down parts on an aircraft breakout for logistics. So each grouping actually represents a place on the aircraft., hence the reason for quantity in each group needing to be accurate, but currently, it will take the group from lines 19 through 56 and total its quantity the same as lines 57 through 94, when it should read the way i illustrated in column 'M'. I want to have a single occurrence of every part with its quantity for where it lies.

Comment: I am still lost. I still don't understand what you want to do and you don't show the essential formulas. :(

Comment: Are the formulas not showing in the spreadsheet? If not, I will add it again or just place formulas direct.

Comment: Column 'L' formula as follows=SUMIFS(K:K,I:I,I2)

Comment: Yes, they are - I never used an online spreadsheet before.

Comment: Column 'L' formula as follows =SUMIFS(K:K,I:I,I2). The concatenates are typical, but all formulas are in the spreadsheet. 38 total parts for left position on aircraft for first 38 lines, then I have another 10,000 random parts for different places after that, the exact same 38 parts from before, for the right hand side of the aircraft. I don't want the left and right to be total of 76, together with sumifs formula, I need each to show quantity of 38 for each section, highlighted on the spreadsheet columns 'L' and 'M'. I know some German too, but I know more about engineering drawings, lol.

Comment: My example of 10,000 parts isn't reflected in the spreadsheet I shared by the way, 76mb is too much, but the idea should convey all the same. I need column 'L' to formulate with quantity that looks like it does in column 'M'. I only added 'M' to show desired effect. Otherwise, I have to go in and manually grab sections, put on another sheet, use sumifs formula, then put back on original sheet, and with almost 300,000 lines, that is not efficient. I know there has to be a way, but I need new perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not ideal because of size of file, but any solution would suffer from that to some extent or another.

Use two helper columns, one to keep a running total top-down, and another to keep a running total bottom-up. Assuming column I is your identified for what constitutes a "group", and K has the quantities in question, I'll use X and Y as my helper columns.
In X1, put 0 (zero), then in X2, to keep a running total for the current group:

```
=K2+X1*(I2=I1)
```

This takes the current value and adds to it the running total above, but only if ID matches, otherwise start again from the current quantity.
Similarly in Y2, but slightly different:

```
=(K3+Y3)*(I2=I3)
```

This adds the quantity below to the running total below if IDs match, otherwise start again at zero.
Copy both formulas down columns X and Y. Y1 can have any label you like.

Now, the magic of this is that the quantity for the group is the sum of those two totals, because the count in opposite directions and have an offset of a row so you don't double count anything. Also they can be copied down as you add more data. Put a simple =SUM(X2:Y2) formula in whatever column you want to hold the final total.

Downside of this approach is that you have a huge dependency tree here so when a single value changes, everything gets recalculated like a room full of dominoes. If that becomes a big deal, you could copy and paste values in all but the top row of X and Y while making lots of changes to the data, then copy down to the bottom and go for a walk/coffee/beer while it calculates. Then paste values again.

I'm generally not a fan of solutions which require the data to be sorted in a particular way, but it seems like that is the only way your data makes sense anyway as it is very hierarchical so I am not too worried about it getting sorted another way in this specific scenario.